# Docker container in Azure /bin/sh: 1: [gunicorn,: not found

Tags: python, azure, docker

I have the following problem:

I have a small web app written in Python. I run it in a docker container. Locally the web app works fine. When I deploy the container to Azure App Service I get the following error:

`2021-09-07T15:11:32.980846527Z /bin/sh: 1: [gunicorn,: not found`

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 5000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "dash_app\dashboard:server"]
```

And here is the requirements.txt

```
flask
gunicorn
dash
pandas
```

I am new to docker and python. From my understanding pip install should install the latest version of everything from requirements.txt in the container itself. I don't understand why the gunicorn cannot be found.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That error generally means your `CMD` syntax isn't actually a valid JSON array.  Here I'm guessing `\d` isn't a valid backslash-escape; do you need `\\ ` to escape the backslash, or to use a Python package name `dash_app.dashboard:server`?

Comment: @HeadInTheClouds, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the executable. This array form is the preferred format of `CMD`. Any additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the array.

That is, you should provide the full path to `gunicorn` executable, or use the shell format:

```
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 dash_app\dashboard:server
```